# Programming undervoltage lockout in Boost(Step up) converter

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, boost, power-electronics

Requirement is to convert 3 V (1.5 x 2 alkaline batteries) dc voltage to 5 V Dc voltage. I know battery voltage decrease with the use and i am required to set a threshold voltage so that if battery voltage decreases below threshold point IC Should not supply the voltage to the device. How can i achieve this? (Required threshold voltage is around 2.1V) 
{I am supposed to achieve this using TPS61200 boost converter}. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the data sheet tells you about the UVLO mpin: -

> 10.3.1.6 Undervoltage Lockout
>
> An undervoltage lockout function prevents the main output at VOUT from
>   being supplied if the voltage at the UVLO pin drops below 0.25 V. When
>   using a resistive divider at the voltage to be monitored, for example
>   the supply voltage, any threshold for the monitored voltage can be
>   programmed. If in undervoltage lockout mode, the device still
>   maintains its supply voltage at VAUX, and it is not turned off until
>   EN is programmed low. This undervoltage lockout function is
>   implemented in order to prevent the malfunctioning of the converter.

So, using a two-resistor potential divider you can set the booster to inhibit at a supply voltage below 2.1 volts - make the pot-divider such that it divides 2.1 volts to 0.25 volts. Here is an example: -

[image]

R14 and R16 in this example set the lock-out voltage to be 2.5 volts because they pot down the voltage by 10:1.